# Error 502 bad gateway

Tags: apt, software-installation, kali-linux, gateway

I can't install anything with apt...
I just installed kali-linux 2017.3...
after updating and upgrading 700MB files:The last lines of the output of `apt upgrade`:

```
Err:2 http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 libstdc++-6-dev amd64 6.4.0-10
  502  Bad Gateway
Get:1 http://kali.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 systemd amd64 235-3 [2,946 kB]
Err:4 http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 git-man all 1:2.15.0-1 
  502  Bad Gateway
Err:6 http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 python3-simplejson amd64 3.12.0-1
  502  Bad Gateway
Get:3 http://kali.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 libnss3 amd64 2:3.34-1 [1,161 kB]
Err:8 http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 ruby-yajl amd64 1.2.0-3.1
  502  Bad Gateway
Get:5 http://kali.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 network-manager amd64 1.10.0-1 [2,136 kB]
Err:10 http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 xauth amd64 1:1.0.10-1
  502  Bad Gateway
Get:5 http://kali.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 network-manager amd64 1.10.0-1 [2,136 kB]
Get:7 http://kali.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 ruby-http-parser.rb amd64 0.6.0-4 [10.2 kB]
Get:9 http://kali.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 t1utils amd64 1.41-2 [62.0 kB]
Fetched 5,976 kB in 1min 26s (69.1 kB/s)                                       
E: Failed to fetch http://http.kali.org/kali/pool/main/g/gcc-6/libstdc++-6-dev_6.4.0-10_amd64.deb  502  Bad Gateway
E: Failed to fetch http://http.kali.org/kali/pool/main/g/git/git-man_2.15.0-1_all.deb  502  Bad Gateway
E: Failed to fetch http://http.kali.org/kali/pool/main/s/simplejson/python3-simplejson_3.12.0-1_amd64.deb  502  Bad Gateway
E: Failed to fetch http://http.kali.org/kali/pool/main/r/ruby-yajl/ruby-yajl_1.2.0-3.1_amd64.deb  502  Bad Gateway
E: Failed to fetch http://http.kali.org/kali/pool/main/x/xauth/xauth_1.0.10-1_amd64.deb  502  Bad Gateway
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?



root@kali:~# apt-get install tor
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libzstd1 tor-geoipdb torsocks
Suggested packages:
  mixmaster torbrowser-launcher tor-arm apparmor-utils obfsproxy obfs4proxy
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libzstd1 tor tor-geoipdb torsocks
0 upgraded, 4 newly installed, 0 to remove and 428 not upgraded.
Need to get 1,663 kB/2,989 kB of archives.
After this operation, 11.7 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Err:2 http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 torsocks amd64 2.2.0-2 
  502  Bad Gateway
Get:1 http://kali.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 tor amd64 0.3.1.8-2 [1,590 kB]
Fetched 1,590 kB in 39s (40.2 kB/s)                                            
E: Failed to fetch http://http.kali.org/kali/pool/main/t/torsocks/torsocks_2.2.0-2_amd64.deb  502  Bad Gateway
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

How can i fix this problem?anyone can help?

I tried to find solution!but i didn't find anything!or their were not useful...

I've also added these two lines to Nginx configuration file `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`:

```
http {
    ...
    fastcgi_buffers 8 16k;
    fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;
    ...
}
```

After adding these two lines...i could install some packages...but not all of them...Like this:

```
root@kali:~# apt install python3-pip
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libpython3-dev libpython3.6-dev python3-crypto python3-dev python3-keyring
  python3-keyrings.alt python3-pkg-resources python3-secretstorage
  python3-setuptools python3-wheel python3.6-dev
Suggested packages:
  python-crypto-doc libkf5wallet-bin python-secretstorage-doc
  python-setuptools-doc
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libpython3-dev libpython3.6-dev python3-crypto python3-dev python3-keyring
  python3-keyrings.alt python3-pip python3-secretstorage python3-setuptools
  python3-wheel python3.6-dev
The following packages will be upgraded:
  python3-pkg-resources
1 upgraded, 11 newly installed, 0 to remove and 427 not upgraded.
Need to get 3,766 kB/3,907 kB of archives.
After this operation, 19.9 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Err:3 http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 python3-crypto amd64 2.6.1-8
  502  Bad Gateway
Get:1 http://kali.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 libpython3.6-dev amd64 3.6.3-1 [2,482 kB]
Err:5 http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 python3-dev amd64 3.6.3-2
  502  Bad Gateway
Err:7 http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 python3-keyring all 10.4.0-1
  502  Bad Gateway
Get:2 http://kali.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 libpython3-dev amd64 3.6.3-2 [19.2 kB]
Get:4 http://kali.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 python3.6-dev amd64 3.6.3-1 [518 kB]
Err:9 http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 python3-pip all 9.0.1-2
  502  Bad Gateway
Get:6 http://kali.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 python3-secretstorage all 2.3.1-2 [14.2 kB]
Err:11 http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 python3-wheel all 0.29.0-2
  502  Bad Gateway
Get:8 http://kali.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 python3-keyrings.alt all 2.2-2 [16.6 kB]
Get:10 http://kali.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 python3-setuptools all 36.7.1-1 [223 kB]
Fetched 3,274 kB in 1min 22s (39.8 kB/s)      
E: Failed to fetch http://http.kali.org/kali/pool/main/p/python-crypto/python3-crypto_2.6.1-8_amd64.deb  502  Bad Gateway
E: Failed to fetch http://http.kali.org/kali/pool/main/p/python3-defaults/python3-dev_3.6.3-2_amd64.deb  502  Bad Gateway
E: Failed to fetch http://http.kali.org/kali/pool/main/p/python-keyring/python3-keyring_10.4.0-1_all.deb  502  Bad Gateway
E: Failed to fetch http://http.kali.org/kali/pool/main/p/python-pip/python3-pip_9.0.1-2_all.deb  502  Bad Gateway
E: Failed to fetch http://http.kali.org/kali/pool/main/w/wheel/python3-wheel_0.29.0-2_all.deb  502  Bad Gateway
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

Output of `ps aux | grep php`:

```
root      4858  0.0  0.0  12720   916 pts/0    S+   00:43   0:00 grep php
```

Output of `sudo apt-get remove php5 php5-cgi php5-fpm`:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package 'php5' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'php5-cgi' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'php5-fpm' is not installed, so not removed
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 428 not upgraded.
```

Output of `sudo apt-get install php5 php5-cgi php5-fpm`:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package php5 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

Package php5-fpm is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

Package php5-cgi is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'php5' has no installation candidate
E: Package 'php5-cgi' has no installation candidate
E: Package 'php5-fpm' has no installation candidate
```

Output of `nano /etc/apt/sources.list`:

```
# deb cdrom:[Debian GNU/Linux 2017.3 _Kali-rolling_ - Official Snapshot amd64 L$

#deb cdrom:[Debian GNU/Linux 2017.3 _Kali-rolling_ - Official Snapshot amd64 LI$
#deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main contrib non-free
deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main non-free contrib
```

Output of `nano /etc/nginx/nginx.conf`:

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

events {
    worker_connections 768;
    # multi_accept on;
}

http {

    ##
    # Basic Settings
    ##

    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    # server_tokens off;

    # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
    # server_name_in_redirect off;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    ##
    # SSL Settings
    ##

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    ##
    # Logging Settings
    ##

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    ##
    # Gzip Settings
    ##

    gzip on;

    # gzip_vary on;
    # gzip_proxied any;
    # gzip_comp_level 6;
    # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    # gzip_http_version 1.1;
    # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

    ##
    # Virtual Host Configs
    ##

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}


#mail {
#   # See sample authentication script at:
#   # http://wiki.nginx.org/ImapAuthenticateWithApachePhpScript
# 
#   # auth_http localhost/auth.php;
#   # pop3_capabilities "TOP" "USER";
#   # imap_capabilities "IMAP4rev1" "UIDPLUS";
# 
#   server {
#       listen     localhost:110;
#       protocol   pop3;
#       proxy      on;
#   }
# 
#   server {
#       listen     localhost:143;
#       protocol   imap;
#       proxy      on;
#   }
#}


http {
    ...
    fastcgi_buffers 8 16k;
    fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;
    ...
}
```

Output of `apt-get update`:

```
Hit:1 http://kali.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/kali kali-rolling InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
```

`apt-get upgrade`:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  dissy libgom-1.0-common libqcustomplot1.3 python-rsvg
Use 'apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages have been kept back:
  bdfproxy glusterfs-common gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly gvfs gvfs-backends
  gvfs-daemons gvfs-fuse gvfs-libs libavcodec57 libavfilter6 libavformat57
  libavresample3 libavutil55 libgdal20 libopencv-calib3d3.2
  libopencv-contrib3.2 libopencv-core3.2 libopencv-features2d3.2
  libopencv-flann3.2 libopencv-highgui3.2 libopencv-imgcodecs3.2
  libopencv-imgproc3.2 libopencv-ml3.2 libopencv-objdetect3.2
  libopencv-photo3.2 libopencv-shape3.2 libopencv-stitching3.2
  libopencv-superres3.2 libopencv-video3.2 libopencv-videoio3.2
  libopencv-videostab3.2 libopencv-viz3.2 libpostproc54 libswresample2
  libswscale4 linux-image-4.13.0-kali1-amd64 mariadb-client-10.1
  mariadb-server-10.1 mariadb-server-core-10.1 mitmproxy ruby-http-parser.rb
  systemd-sysv tcpflow
The following packages will be upgraded:
  aircrack-ng apt apt-utils arj arp-scan axel binutils binutils-common
  binutils-x86-64-linux-gnu cabextract cgpt cheese-common console-setup
  console-setup-linux couchdb cpp-7 dbus dbus-user-session dbus-x11 debconf
  debconf-i18n debianutils dirmngr dmeventd dmsetup dsniff eog exim4-base
  exim4-config exim4-daemon-light exploitdb fakeroot findutils firefox-esr
  flasm fontconfig fontconfig-config fonts-noto-mono g++-7 galera-3 gcc-6-base
  gcc-7 gcc-7-base gdal-bin gdal-data gdm3 geoip-database geoip-database-extra
  gir1.2-freedesktop gir1.2-gdm-1.0 gir1.2-glib-2.0
  gir1.2-javascriptcoregtk-4.0 gir1.2-json-1.0 gir1.2-mutter-1
  gir1.2-networkmanager-1.0 gir1.2-nmgtk-1.0 gir1.2-webkit2-4.0 git git-man
  gjs gnome-shell gnome-shell-common gnome-software gnome-software-common
  gnome-sushi gnome-tweak-tool gnupg gnupg-l10n gnupg-utils gnuplot
  gnuplot-data gnuplot-qt gpg gpg-agent gpg-wks-client gpg-wks-server gpgconf
  gpgsm gpgv gvfs-bin intel-microcode iproute2 iso-codes kali-desktop-common
  kali-desktop-gnome kali-desktop-live kali-linux kali-linux-full
  keyboard-configuration libaio1 libapache2-mod-php7.0 libapparmor1
  libappstream-glib8 libapr1 libaprutil1 libaprutil1-dbd-sqlite3
  libaprutil1-ldap libapt-inst2.0 libapt-pkg5.0 libasan3 libasan4 libass9
  libassuan0 libatinject-jsr330-api-java libatomic1 libaudit-common libaudit1
  libbfio1 libbinutils libbsd0 libc-bin libc-dev-bin libc-l10n libc6 libc6-dbg
  libc6-dev libcc1-0 libcdparanoia0 libcgi-fast-perl libcheese-gtk25
  libcheese8 libcilkrts5 libconfig9 libdbd-sqlite3-perl libdbus-1-3
  libdbus-glib-1-2 libdevel-partialdump-perl libdevel-stacktrace-perl
  libdevmapper-event1.02.1 libdevmapper1.02.1 libdrm-amdgpu1 libdrm-common
  libdrm-dev libdrm-intel1 libdrm-nouveau2 libdrm-radeon1 libdrm2 libegl-mesa0
  libegl1 libegl1-mesa libepoxy0 libexpat1 libexpat1-dev libfaad2 libfakeroot
  libfcgi-bin libfcgi0ldbl libfontconfig1 libfribidi0 libfwupd2 libgbm1
  libgcab-1.0-0 libgcc-6-dev libgcc-7-dev libgcc1 libgcrypt20 libgdcm2.8
  libgdm1 libgeoip1 libgfortran4 libgirepository-1.0-1 libgjs0g libgl1
  libgl1-mesa-dev libgl1-mesa-dri libgl1-mesa-glx libglapi-mesa libgles2
  libglvnd-core-dev libglvnd-dev libglvnd0 libglx-mesa0 libglx0 libgom-1.0-0
  libgomp1 libgpg-error0 libgspell-1-1 libgspell-1-common libhtml-tree-perl
  libhttp-cookies-perl libhttp-server-simple-perl libical2 libidn2-0
  libinput-bin libinput10 libio-all-perl libitm1 libjavascriptcoregtk-4.0-18
  libjson-glib-1.0-0 libjson-glib-1.0-common libkeyutils1 liblsan0
  liblvm2app2.2 liblvm2cmd2.02 liblwgeom-2.4-0 liblwgeom-dev libmailutils5
  libmariadbclient18 libmpx2 libmutter-1-0 libnet-tftp-perl libnetcdf-c++4
  libnm-glib4 libnm-gtk0 libnm-util2 libnm0 libnma0 libnpth0 libnss-myhostname
  libnss3 libobjc-6-dev libobjc4 libodbc1 libopengl0 libopenmpt0 liborc-0.4-0
  libosmesa6 libpam-systemd libpipeline1 libpq5 libpsl5
  libpulse-mainloop-glib0 libpulse0 libpulsedsp libquadmath0
  librygel-core-2.6-2 librygel-db-2.6-2 librygel-renderer-2.6-2
  librygel-server-2.6-2 libserf-1-1 libsmbclient libsoxr0 libsqlite3-0
  libstdc++-6-dev libstdc++-7-dev libstdc++6 libsub-identify-perl libsuperlu5
  libsystemd0 libtasn1-6 libterm-readline-gnu-perl libtevent0
  libtracker-control-2.0-0 libtracker-miner-2.0-0 libtracker-sparql-2.0-0
  libtsan0 libubsan0 libudev1 libuv1 libva-drm2 libva-x11-2 libva2
  libvariable-magic-perl libvisual-0.4-0 libwayland-egl1-mesa libwbclient0
  libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37 libwebp6 libwebpdemux2 libwebpmux3 libwww-perl
  libxatracker2 libxml-libxml-perl libxml-namespacesupport-perl libxml2
  libxres1 libxslt1.1 libyara3 linux-libc-dev locales locales-all lvm2
  mailutils mailutils-common man-db mariadb-client-core-10.1 mariadb-common
  mesa-common-dev mesa-va-drivers mesa-vdpau-drivers metasploit-framework
  mimikatz mousetweaks multiarch-support mutter mutter-common nano ncompress
  ndiff network-manager network-manager-gnome nishang nmap nmap-common
  odbcinst odbcinst1debian2 php php-common php-mysql php7.0 php7.0-cli
  php7.0-common php7.0-json php7.0-mysql php7.0-opcache php7.0-readline
  postgresql postgresql-10 postgresql-client-10 postgresql-client-common
  postgresql-common pulseaudio pulseaudio-module-bluetooth pulseaudio-utils
  python-cairo python-construct python-crypto python-cryptography
  python-enum34 python-faraday python-gdal python-gi python-glade2
  python-gobject python-gobject-2 python-gtk2 python-libxml2 python-libxslt1
  python-m2crypto python-pefile python-pkg-resources python-rsvg python-samba
  python-setuptools python-simplejson python-sip python-yara python3-cairo
  python3-cryptography python3-cups python3-debconf python3-gi
  python3-gi-cairo python3-pkg-resources python3-pyatspi python3-sip recon-ng
  responder rfkill ruby-msgpack ruby-yajl rygel samba samba-common
  samba-common-bin samba-dsdb-modules samba-libs samba-vfs-modules
  sensible-utils set smbclient socat sparta sqlite3 sqlitebrowser stunnel4
  systemd t1utils tracker tracker-extract tracker-miner-fs udev va-driver-all
  vboot-kernel-utils vboot-utils vlan whatweb winexe xauth xpdf xsltproc
  zaproxy zenity zenity-common zenmap
385 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 43 not upgraded.
Need to get 1,553 kB/566 MB of archives.
After this operation, 28.0 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Err:2 http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 ruby-yajl amd64 1.2.0-3.1
  502  Bad Gateway
Get:1 http://kali.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 git-man all 1:2.15.0-1 [1,511 kB]
Fetched 1,511 kB in 31s (48.5 kB/s)                                            
E: Failed to fetch http://http.kali.org/kali/pool/main/r/ruby-yajl/ruby-yajl_1.2.0-3.1_amd64.deb  502  Bad Gateway
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

Comment: How nginx is related to apt?

Comment: i'm a beginner... if u know about that let me know how ? @karnauskas

Comment: nginx should be unrelated at all unless you run your own kali linux mirror. Can you run `apt-get update` before `apt-get upgrade`?

Comment: @karnauskas yes many times,check the edited question...

Comment: The italian mirror which is the nearest to your geographical location is down or has sync issues. It will be fixed itself. Try again after some time. You can also change your repository to **deb http://repo.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main non-free contrib**

Comment: I'm hitting number of repos rejecting http.
Update your `/etc/apt/sources.list` with http->https.